# Can't install gems with rbenv on Windows bash

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, rbenv

I've searched far and wide for a question, a blog, anything that can solve this particular error, but I can't find it.

Basically, running bash (well, zsh) on Windows 10. I installed rbenv and ruby build through their respective git repos. I set up a project, set the rbenv version (using 2.3.3 but it doesn't work on 2.4.0 either), and try to install a gem.

> ➜  app git:(master) ✗ gem install bundler
>
> /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error:
> /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so:
> undefined symbol: parse_numeric_port

Any idea how to repair this? An issue with linux on Windows or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What if you install Ruby with `apt-get install ruby` instead?

Comment: @anothermh I can do it then, but Windows' Ubuntu install is old and the repositories are ancient, so it only goes up to 1.9.3, and I can't install without sudo.

Comment: You don't specify this in your post: did you successfully build Ruby? Does `ruby -v` work for you and show the version that you built with rbenv?

Comment: Yes, I have verified the ruby install, have verified `which gem` and `gem env home`, etc.

Comment: Can you try the instructions at https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10 and see if you get any farther?

Comment: I also ran into the same problem. The build log shows the following errors. `configuring socket
unexpected fd-passing recvmsg() with MSG_PEEK behavor on x86_64-linux: fd allocation expected.`, `raddrinfo.c: In function ‘numeric_getaddrinfo’:
raddrinfo.c:214:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘parse_numeric_port’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`.

Comment: I reverted to older Ruby, and Ruby 2.2.7 seems to be working with bash in Windows 10. `gem install` works now, although the build is still throwing the same errors as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Have you installed build-essential package? Additionally, are you using Bash On Windows or Windows Subsystem for Linux?